# Azure cloud shell with VNET - "Name or service not know" when pinging organization's host

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to deploy azure function app that uses python requests to organization private API endpoint to get some data. The problem is that even when VNET is configured I still don't have the access to the host.

I get replies when pinging host from cmd but doing this from azure cloud shell resolves in 'Name or service not known'.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I had some issues with deploying cloud shell in VNet (new to Azure and networking). Is there a simpler way to check i.e. my VNet can communicate with 'example.enterprise.com' host and then integrate Azure function?

Comment: Just connect your function in the cloud shell which is in the same VNet.

Comment: Could you provide some resources on how to do that?

Comment: What do mean by resources? the shell command is enough.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, this requirement needs to be finished with the following steps:

1. create the Azure cloud shell in the VNet
2. integrate the Azure function with the VNet that the cloud shell in
3. create a private endpoint of the API in that VNet

When you finish all the above steps, you can access the API through the private endpoint from the function.